# Do I have to prefix sql parameter name with @ sign when adding SqlParameters to the collection?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, parameters, sqlclient

In VB.NET we are adding sql parameters without the @ sign and application is working fine:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("in_id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) says syntax for parameter placeholders depends on the data source and `System.Data.SqlClient` uses named parameters in the format `@parametername`.

We are porting the code from Oracle and the same page says for `System.Data.OracleClient` it uses named parameters in the format `:parmname (or parmname)`, which means the colon is not required.

The page does not explicitly say parameters without @ sign is OK for the `Data.SqlClient`.

Is the @ sign required before the parameter name (input or output parameter) when using the `Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: Sounds like you already answered your question: "...application is working fine."

Comment: Yes, working fine in our unit test environment. I'm trying to make sure before sending a bunch of code to producion only to find out later on that's a problem.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, since I can't find anywhere in the MSDN documentation where it says that it does officially support it or is recommended to use it that way.  Personally I wish it was enforced that all DB providers were required to work that way since it would make them more interchangeable, but it seems like all their examples imply that you should be prefixing the parameter names with the `@`.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Yes, this feature is not documented. However, if you could rely on it would be documented.

Comment: Thank all for the comments and reference to the answer. Read that other question and yes, it is better to manually prefix the parameter name with the @ sign.

Comment: As a separate topic, it is frustrating not finding that other question/answer using the search box; I tried for like 15 minutes with different sets of  keywords. Even the results you get when you decide to type the questioin using same kewords used in your original search is different, even this referenced question did not show up then. Is it only me?? Oh well, yes it might be, I'm Only You after all.

Comment: I find Google to be a much more accurate search engine for finding stuff on this site.

Comment: OK, good to know. Will use that then. Thanks Seteve.